# Keep the current position in the center of the timeline in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, adobe

In Adobe Premiere, the current position in the Timeline panel often moves to the right end (while playing) so I can't see what is going to play next.

[image]

Is there any hotkey to fast forward the timeline (not the current position) so the current position will be at the center. Or maybe there is an option to keep the current position always in the middle of the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the Shift-Key pressed and move your mouse wheel to scroll the timeline horizontally. This works when not playing as well as when playing but only if the timeline is not auto-scrolling.

If you want to keep the playhead centered, go to Edit-Menu -> Preferences -> Timeline and select "Smooth Scroll" where it says "Timeline Playback Auto-Scrolling", see also the screenshot:

One more tip: the thin blue line marking the current position is called the playhead.

[image: where to set smooth scroll]

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess, there is no specific hotkey to center the playhead. 
But "Smooth Scroll" solves the problem. And thanks for the tip!